# footer menu not center aligned

Tags: css

I have a footer divided into 2 rows, i.e footer-top and footer-bottom.

footer-top has text which aligns in center perfectly. However footer-bottom has menu which is not center-aligned.

My html:

```
<div class="page-wrap"> 
    <footer>
        <div class="footer-top">
            Copyright
        </div>
        <div class="footer-bottom">
            <ul class="footermenu">
                <li><a href="#">LEGAL</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PRIVACY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">COPYRIGHT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
 </div>
```

My css:

```
.page-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #8DC63F;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    text-align:center;
}

.footer-top { width: 100%; float: left;padding-top:10px; color: #FFFFFF;}

.footer-bottom {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.footermenu a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font-size: medium;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.footermenu li {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.footermenu {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and here is the

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dT6sC/2/)

Comment: Take a look to this page, it might help http://css-tricks.com/centering-list-items-horizontally-slightly-trickier-than-you-might-think/ :) good luck ! edit : possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641251/how-do-i-center-list-items-inside-a-ul-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see if it works for you:

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dT6sC/6/)**

I agree with the other answers that you should use `inline-block`, but to do so you'll need to comment out the `float` entries, and rely on `text-align: center`.

CSS, I've gone ahead and commented out the styles you probably don't need:

```
/* new css */
.footermenu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* old css */
.page-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

footer {
    //width: 100%;
    background-color: #8DC63F;
    //display: block;
    //float: left;
    clear: both;
    text-align:center;
}

.footer-top { 
    //width: 100%; 
    //float: left;
    padding-top:10px; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.footer-bottom {
    width: 100%;
    //text-align: center;
    //float: left;
    //display: inline-block;
}

.footermenu a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    //float: left;
    font-size: medium;
    //list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.footermenu li {
    //width: auto;
    //float: left;
    //text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    //text-decoration: none;
}
.footermenu {
    //text-decoration: none;
    //width: auto;
    //text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `display: inline-block` to `.footermenu`
[Example...](http://jsfiddle.net/m_ms27/zJGtE/)

Comment: but even in this footermenu is not center aligning

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that it's centered :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your footer menu css

```
.footermenu {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 266px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dT6sC/4/

Comment: i will be adding more li items to it so i don't want to fix the width to 266px...any other way?

Comment: you can use a center tag inside your ul :

`<ul class="footermenu">
    <center>
     <li><a href="#">LEGAL</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PRIVACY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">COPYRIGHT</a></li>
   </center>
</ul>`